# What is the logic behind doing a full outer join with multiple join statements?

Tags: sql-server, full-outer-join

```
SELECT MP.*
FROM SurveyFrontend..WebResult WR
JOIN MeetingHistory MH
ON MH.WebResultID=WR.WebResultID
JOIN Meeting M
ON MH.MeetingID=M.MeetingID
JOIN MeetingPlanner MP
ON MP.MeetingPlannerID=M.MeetingPlannerID
WHERE PrimaryEntityID=2424
AND WR.TimeResultTaken>='1/1/2016'
AND CardSet=2
```

I've looked it up but I can't find any examples on how to do a full outer join with multiple joins. I want to pull the exact opposite of the above query.

How would I go about doing this?

Here is exactly what I'm looking for:

[image: SQL FULL OUTER JOIN]

Updated code:

```
SELECT MP.*
FROM SurveyFrontend..WebResult WR
FULL OUTER JOIN MeetingHistory MH
ON MH.WebResultID=WR.WebResultID
FULL OUTER JOIN Meeting M
ON MH.MeetingID=M.MeetingID
FULL OUTER JOIN MeetingPlanner MP
ON MP.MeetingPlannerID=M.MeetingPlannerID
WHERE PrimaryEntityID=2424
AND WR.TimeResultTaken>='1/1/2016'
AND CardSet=2
AND (MH.WebResultID IS NULL
OR   MH.MeetingID IS NULL
OR   MP.MeetingPlannerID IS NULL
OR   WR.WebResultID IS NULL
OR   M.MeetingID IS NULL
OR   M.MeetingPlannerID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Replace all instances of `JOIN` here (which is implicitly an `INNER JOIN`) with `FULL OUTER JOIN`, `WHERE` anyA key(s) are `NULL` or any B keys are `NULL`. The syntax is shown in the image you cropped: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Comment: I know that part but I don't know what to put in the WHERE clause. Thank you though!

Comment: Oh nvm, you edited your comment. Let me try that out.

Comment: I'm not getting any returns with the updated statement*

Comment: I also switched the and's to or's

Answer (score 1):

`full outer join` returns all rows which match `on` condition *and* all rows from left table which don't match condition *and* all rows from right table which don't match condition. Any `where` restrictions reduce `full outer join` to `left`, `right`, or `inner join`. Some examples:

```
create table #a(id int, name varchar(10))
insert #a values (1,'test1'),(2,'test2'),(3,'test3')
create table #b(id int, name varchar(10))
insert #b values (1,'test1'),(4,'test4'),(5,'test5')

select a.id aid,a.name aname, b.id bid,b.name bname
from #a a full outer join #b b on a.id=b.id

--same as left join
select a.id aid,a.name aname, b.id bid,b.name bname
from #a a full outer join #b b on a.id=b.id
where a.id=2

--same as right join
select a.id aid,a.name aname, b.id bid,b.name bname
from #a a full outer join #b b on a.id=b.id
where b.id=4

--same as inner join
select a.id aid,a.name aname, b.id bid,b.name bname
from #a a full outer join #b b on a.id=b.id
where a.id=1 and b.id=1

--same as inner join better example
select a.id aid,a.name aname, b.id bid,b.name bname
from #a a full outer join #b b on a.id=b.id
where a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Tests of `is null` in the where clause don't always reduce full outer to a left, right, or inner join. Specifically `LeftPK is null or RightPK is null` gives rows from both side that don't have matches.